# Multiple TransactionManagers in SpringBoot @Transactional not working?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have created two spring boot custom startes which access each different Databases.
This starters can be included in other projects as a dependency to handle all database access.
It might be possible that they are both included, but it may also be possible that only one of them is included - depending of the kind of project.

Now I have a project which needs both of them. And I am getting the following error:

```
No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.transaction.TransactionManager' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: db1TransactionManager,db2TransactionManager
```

In both custom startes I have annotated the service class by defining the Transactionmanager to be used:

Starter 1:

```
@Transactional(transactionManager = "db1TransactionManager")
public class Db1ServiceImpl implements Db1Service {
```

Starter 2:

```
@Transactional(transactionManager = "db2TransactionManager")
public class Db2ServiceImpl implements Db2Service {
```

Am I missing something additional? I would have expected that using @Transactional will be enough?

Here is the full stacktrace of the error:

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException$InternalServerError: 500 : "{"timestamp":"2023-04-19T07:31:58.223+02:00","message":"Unexpected error","detailedMessage":"No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.transaction.TransactionManager' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: db1TransactionManager,db2TransactionManager","errorCode":"-1","stacktrace":null,"exceptionType":null,"subErrors":null}"
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException.create(HttpServerErrorException.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:170) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:122) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:819) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:777) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:711) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:602) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
    at com.service.controller.MgmController.getAll(MgmController.java:32) ~[classes!/:1.0.0]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor58.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1071) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:964) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:670) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar!/:4.0.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:779) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar!/:4.0.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.68.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:337) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar!/:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar!/:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar!/:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar!/:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar!/:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar!/:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar!/:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar!/:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar!/:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar!/:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar!/:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar!/:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar!/:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar!/:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar!/:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar!/:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter.doFilterInternal(DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter.java:58) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar!/:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar!/:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:237) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar!/:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:223) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar!/:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar!/:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:223) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar!/:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:217) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar!/:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar!/:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.servlet.filter.Saml2WebSsoAuthenticationRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(Saml2WebSsoAuthenticationRequestFilter.java:192) ~[spring-security-saml2-service-provider-5.7.4.jar!/:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar!/:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar!/:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar!/:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar!/:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar!/:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar!/:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar!/:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:112) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar!/:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar!/:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar!/:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar!/:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar!/:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar!/:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar!/:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:221) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar!/:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar!/:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.7.5.jar!/:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:769) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar!/:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: Check the stacktrace. There are other parts of Spring (especially Spring Data) that require a single transactionmanger or explicitly setup with a transactionmanager.

Comment: Specify separated `@Qualifier("someName")` for each transaction manager bean you defined to distinguish them.

Comment: Please add the **full stacktrace** not just a snippet.

Comment: I added the whole stacktrace to my original posting.

Comment: Looks like you are retrieving it from somewhere else, we need the stacktrace of the service handling the request, not the one issuing the request.

Answer (score 0):

#### Explanation

The use of multiple transaction managers of same priority (i.e., without `@Primary` annotation on one of them) in your Spring context is totally fine if you carefully look after their usages and always use the specific ones.

The error that you are facing is most probably due to use of `@Transactional` without specifying correct `transactionManager`. In this case, Spring Framework implicitly injects TransactionManager from the context (and assumes that there is a single match which is not your case).

It's worth looking through your project and / or its dependencies and you will probably find either a `@Transactional` method which is being called or explicit injection of a `@TransactionManager`.

#### Example

For instance, suppose that you have a configuration

```
@Configuration
public class TransactionManagerConfig {

  @Bean
  public TransactionManager firstTransactionManager() {
    return new CustomTransactionManager();
  }

  @Bean
  public TransactionManager secondTransactionManager() {
    return new CustomTransactionManager();
  }
}
```

(where `CustomTransactionManager` is some your implementation)

and a repository with 2 methods which use each of the transaction managers:

```
@Repository
public class GeneralEntityRepository {

  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager entityManager;

  @Transactional("firstTransactionManager")
  public GeneralEntity getGeneralEntityWithId1() {
    return entityManager.find(GeneralEntity.class, 1);
  }

  @Transactional("secondTransactionManager")
  public GeneralEntity getGeneralEntityWithId2() {
    return entityManager.find(GeneralEntity.class, 2);
  }
}
```

then everything will work fine as Spring knows which manager to use.

However, if you add a third method without explicit transaction manager specification:

```
  @Transactional
  public GeneralEntity getGeneralEntityWithId3() {
    return entityManager.find(GeneralEntity.class, 2);
  }
```

then you will get an exception upon calling it:

```
// this is ok
GeneralEntity entity1 = generalEntityRepository.getGeneralEntityWithId1();

// this is also ok
GeneralEntity entity2 = generalEntityRepository.getGeneralEntityWithId2();
    
// this produces an exception
GeneralEntity entity3 = generalEntityRepository.getGeneralEntityWithId3();
System.out.println("GeneralEntity with id 3 = " + entity3);
```

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.transaction.TransactionManager' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: firstTransactionManager,secondTransactionManager
```

This can be fixed by either specifying the transaction manager in `@Transactional` or by annotating one of them as `@Primary`.

See more information about `@Transactional` annotation in the official doc: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html

Answer (score -1):

You have 2 ambiguous beans existing in the context. Please distinguish them by specifying a `@Qualifier` name for each bean and use it in the `@Transactional` value.

Ref: [Multiple Transaction Managers with @Transactional](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/data-access.html#tx-multiple-tx-mgrs-with-attransactional)

Comment: You can just use the name and don't need an `@Qualifier`. The error is probably coming from Spring Data JPA that requires a single transaction manager or one marked as `@Primary` or explicitly setup for the different entitymanagers/datasources.

Comment: @M.Deinum The error OP mentioned is caused by type ambiguity in Spring context no matter Spring Data or any other packages. Yes you can resolve it simply and efficiently by using `@Primary`. The `@Qualifier` give you more controls tho. Ref: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers

Comment: no it doesn't and the erorr isn't thrown by his own services but Spring Data components, so adding qualifiers si,ply won't help.

Comment: @Càphêđen this error appears when 'someone' is trying to inject the bean of this type without specifying its name or qualifier. The code by OP is not the culprit as it specifies the name in 'transactionManager' parameter (which is alias for 'value'). There should be some another code which requires transaction manager but does not specify the name.